# Is ‘I moved position of something’ valid?

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

Instead of saying ‘I changed position of something’, can I say ‘I moved position of something’? I know both are unnatural, but I want to know of its validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. *Move position* functions as a phrasal verb, but it is intransitive.

You can say *I moved position* or *The waiter moved position*, but you can't say *I moved position of something*.

You can, however, say *I moved the position of something*: this is not using the phrasal verb *move position*, but normal transitive *move*.